# Is there a way to use " from math import * " in a function?

Tags: python, function

```
def mathImport():
  from math import *
```

I dont know if it is possible and if it isn't, is there a other way to do something like this?

Comment: ```    def projectX():
    ^
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level ``` i get this error

Comment: You can just use the methods from math `import math`; then it's clearer where they come from!

Comment: Is `SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level` not clear somehow?

Comment: Why not just import the names you actually need?

Comment: @timgeb That's their question though: "_is there a way to_"? (even though it's practically a bad idea because it throws away namespace information)

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like you've arrived at trying to `import *` in a function to solve a problem, but that is not the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use `*`-imports in nested scopes – i.e. functions or classes. Since variable scope outside of the module `global` namespace is determined at compile time, the runtime name-binding of `*`-imports does not work.

> ## [7.11. The import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)
>
> The wild card form of import — `from module import *` — is only allowed at the module level. Attempting to use it in class or function definitions will raise a SyntaxError.

Explicitly import the names needed:

```
def mathImport():
  from math import ceil
  ...
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer because it has both how to get what's really wanted sensibly and also why a wildcard import won't work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing *everything*, just bring in what you need

```py
def myfunction():
    from math import pi, tan
    # work with imports
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Python [`import` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) the use of `from module import *` is a wild card form and is not allowed to be used in class or function definition. In addition, it isn't a good practice to use this syntax, [see this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) to understand the risks.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot import modules in a function and use them globally, you also cannot import from a string.

There is a module called import lib that you could use to programmatically import modules by string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib

```
>>> module = importlib.import_module("time", ".*")
>>> module.time()
1619787987.921014
>>>
```